# django-ajax-uploader - Unit test fails because of AssertionError

Tags: python, ajax, django, image, upload

I'm using the following app:
https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader

Now, I wrote some tests to check a successful file upload. Everything works fine until reaching the following code sample.

https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader/blob/master/ajaxuploader/views.py#L53

```
success = backend.upload(upload, filename, is_raw)
```

By running through I receive the following error:

```
AssertionError: Cannot read more than the available bytes from the HTTP incoming data.
```

Within debugging I found out, that by stopping the test at that point and calling...

```
request.POST
```

...the test is working fine, no errors appear and the file is uploaded. What the....?
Maybe the file is only uploaded when stopping the test and waiting until it's loaded?

My traceback:

```
AssertionError: Cannot read more than the available bytes from the HTTP incoming data.
Datei "/home/tobi/Projects/academic/src/webapps/django/project/manage.py", Zeile 14, in <module>
  execute_manager(settings)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", Zeile 438, in execute_manager
  utility.execute()
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", Zeile 379, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", Zeile 191, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", Zeile 220, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/test.py", Zeile 8, in handle
  super(Command, self).handle(*args, **kwargs)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", Zeile 37, in handle
  failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", Zeile 360, in run_tests
  result = self.run_suite(suite)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", Zeile 316, in run_suite
  return unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=self.verbosity, failfast=self.failfast).run(suite)
Datei "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", Zeile 151, in run
  test(result)
Datei "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", Zeile 70, in __call__
  return self.run(*args, **kwds)
Datei "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", Zeile 108, in run
  test(result)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", Zeile 299, in __call__
  super(TransactionTestCase, self).__call__(result)
Datei "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", Zeile 391, in __call__
  return self.run(*args, **kwds)
Datei "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", Zeile 327, in run
  testMethod()
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/src/ajaxuploader/ajaxuploader/tests/default_storage_backend.py", Zeile 51, in test_upload_raw_post_local_backend
  HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", Zeile 449, in post
  response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", Zeile 259, in post
  return self.request(**r)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", Zeile 381, in request
  response = self.handler(environ)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", Zeile 84, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", Zeile 111, in get_response
  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/src/ajaxuploader/ajaxuploader/views.py", Zeile 15, in __call__
  return self._ajax_upload(request)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/src/ajaxuploader/ajaxuploader/views.py", Zeile 53, in _ajax_upload
  success = backend.upload(upload, filename, is_raw)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/src/ajaxuploader/ajaxuploader/backends/base.py", Zeile 27, in upload
  chunk = uploaded.read(self.BUFFER_SIZE)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", Zeile 301, in read
  return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
Datei "/home/tobi/Envs/academic/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", Zeile 51, in read
  assert self.__len >= num_bytes, "Cannot read more than the available bytes from the HTTP incoming data."
```